# TextBox Border Style property causing program not to work in C#

Tags: c#, database, properties, controls

I have been trying to learn database programming in C# using the Book "Visual C# and Databases - 2019 Edition: A Step-By-Step Database Programming Tutorial Using Visual Studio 2019". In Chapter 6 (Example 6-1), you need to build a form to View and Edit a Phone Contact List and all the coding necessary. Which I did, the only difference between the project instructions in the book and my project was that I set the Border Style property for the Text Boxes to FixedSingle instead of Fixed3D. When I ran the program and edited a record as instructed, everything went fine with the change. This code was supposed to have cause the actual database to be updated:

`OleDbCommandBuilder phoneAdapterCommands = new OleDbCommandBuilder(phoneAdapter); phoneAdapter.Update(phoneTable);`

However, after closing the program (part to the instructions) and re-opening the program, the previously edited record was back to its original state. I compared my code to the downloaded version that the book provided and found no differences.

As I stated above the only difference between the two programs was the Border Style Property. Can someone please explain why the Border Style Property would prevent a program from running properly?

TIA
David F.

Comment: Please provide more code and more details on the actual program you are writing.  What is the OleDb command pointing to?  Have you checked the underlying data store?  Are you certain it's the border property?  What if you use the sample from the book?

Comment: I don't think it's BorderStyle. Check you Business logic that loads and save the data into database. That's the problem should lie, please update the question if you find actual issue and need further help.

Comment: Your source of data (the database) is probably a file and you're overwriting the file 
updated at run-time with the original one every time you build the Solution. Change that (could be `Copy to Output Directory` or `Build Action`)